# How can I make this method update the quantity on every call

Tags: python

```
class Store(object):
     def __init__(self) :
         self.total_cost=0
         self.goods={} 
     def add_goods(self,goods_name,quantity,cost) :
         cost=cost*quantity
         self.total_cost=self.total_cost+cost
         self.goods[goods_name]=quantity
Q_store=Store()
Q_store.add_goods('shirt',5,10) 
print (Q_store.goods)
print (Q_store.total_goods) 
# it resulted to {'shirt':5} 
# total_goods= 50
Q_store.add_goods('shirt', 5,10)
print (Q_store.goods) 
# it's quantity  remains 5
# the answer remains 5
```

On re-calling the method and printing, its quantity remains 5 instead of 10.
How can I enable the method to keep adjusting the quantity at each call? Because it's seems the quantity remains constant. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show us how exactly do you call this method?

Comment: I made Q_store as the class instance

Comment: Q_store.add_goods ('shirt ', 5,10)

Comment: print (Q_store.goods) resulted {'shirt':5}

Comment: On repeating the calling the quantity still remains 5 which I expected 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```
class Store(object):
     def __init__(self) :
         self.total_cost=0
         self.goods={}
         self.total_goods = ()
     def add_goods(self,goods_name,quantity,cost) :
         cost*=quantity 
         self.total_cost+=cost
         if goods_name in self.goods:
            self.goods[goods_name]+=quantity
         else:
            self.goods[goods_name]=quantity

Q_store=Store()
Q_store.add_goods('shirt',5,10) 
print (Q_store.goods)
print (Q_store.total_cost)  
Q_store.add_goods('shirt', 5,10)
print (Q_store.goods) 
print (Q_store.total_cost)
```

I changed your code to be working one. What you were missing was += to goods dictionary.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot.. I failed to recognize that.. Am so  grateful

Comment: @Udonse no problem. Just remember to [accept my this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you think this is the right one.

Comment: Thanks.. So much grateful for your assistance